# how to rename image names in finder with a custom list of names from an .txt/.mat/excel, etc file (OS X)?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, caffe

I download this training data from 
http://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_dataset.html. However, the training data is not named per category.

The data is named `00163.jpg`,`00463.jpg`,`00522.jpg`, `00707.jpg`, etc. I do have a `.mat` data file that has (1) class and (2) fname. How can I map these class names + respective file name over the actual image names in mac?

I tried manually renaming the files one at a time, but there are ~2500 images.

Comment: Can you show as the sample of `.mat` file and tell us the logic how to catalog these images with .mat file?

Comment: For example, if in `.mat` file, you have a line as `Benz, 00163.jpg`, do you mean you'd like to rename the file to `Benz-00163.jpg`, that's all?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pkx76wll815l5i9/cars_train_annos.mat?dl=0

Comment: The .mat file has two columns: a) class number and b) image ref. (both are text). Here are the images I want to relabel to show either class or class+00163.jpg. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdk848rse5vdnsr/cars_train%20copy.zip?dl=0 It doesn't matter as long is it's somehow sortable.

Comment: @JeremyMolayem - Did you have luck in this? Can you pls share your approach or code snippet?